# Rational License key server and rational license key administrator dependency

Tags: clearcase

We are planning to uninstall and re-install rational license key server in a machine.
Same machine has rational license key administrator and other Rational Tools.

Before uninstalling RLKS we are planning to stop rational services and after installing the RLKS we will start the services.

Will there be any impact on the RLKA or other rational tools due to this uninstallation? As, in do we have to uninstall any of the other tools or Stopping of services would suffice?

Please note that I'm are not upgrading the RLKS, just re-installing the existing version.

Comment: upgrade or re-install, my answer would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Will there be any impact on the RLKA or other rational tools due to this uninstallation?

No if the license server name (and the port) is the same, the other tools should not see the upgrade.

> do we have to uninstall any of the other tools or Stopping of services would suffice?

Stopping the services should be enough.

Note that I am not sure you can upgrade RLKS without upgrading RLKA as well. The [doc mentions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032008):

> The Rational License Key Server includes an administration tool called License Key Administrator or LKAD (available for Windows only) to enter or import license keys and change your license configuration.
>   On UNIX, a set of system administration commands are available to perform similar administrative tasks.

And you need a [32-bits recent enough IM (Installation Manager)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21627779)